# python program debugging product of adjacent numbers

Tags: python, debugging, numpy

I am currently working on project Euler question 8, which asks to find the largest product of 13 adjacent numbers in a 1000 digit long number. I imported the numpy prod function to compute products. It seems to work without the while loop but with the while loop it gives out a weird error message. can someone please explain where I'm going wrong with this?

Code:

```
from numpy import prod

z=\
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
242190226710556263211111093705442175069416589604080
7198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060
5886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

b=[int(i) for i in str(z)]
x=0
i=0

while i <=1000-13:

   if prod(b[i:i+13])>x:
        x=prod(b[i:i+13])
   else:
        pass

print(x)
```

and here is my error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2336, in prod
prod = a.prod
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'prod'
```

Comment: sorry, I seem to have forgotten the i=i+1, but it would still give the same error output

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Python 2.7, seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by converting the multiline string `z` into a list of digits through a list comprehension and the built-in function `int()`:

```
z = """73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
242190226710556263211111093705442175069416589604080
7198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060
5886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"""

digits = [int(num) for num in z.replace('\n', '')]
```

Notice the line breaks have been removed from the original string by invoking `z.replace('\n', '')`.

Then you could use the function `operator.mul()` to get the job done in just one line of code:

```
from operator import mul
x = max(reduce(mul, digits[i:i+13]) for i in range(len(digits) - 12))
```

Python 3 users will need to add the sentence `from functools import reduce` since in the latest versions of the language `reduce()` is no longer a built-in function.

Demo:

```
In [304]: digits
Out[304]: 
[7, 
 3, 
 1,
 6,
 ...
 3,
 4,
 5,
 0]

In [305]: x
Out[305]: 23514624000L
```